# PHP shell_exec with fswebcam not executing

Tags: php, linux, nginx, exec

I'm trying to make a simple webpage with a button which will call fswebcam program to update the photo viewed also by this paged.

I've started from this:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('/usr/bin/fswebcam -S 1 -r 640x480 -q /var/www/html/foto.jpg');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

But it doesn't execute. I've added www-data user to video group. I also checked logs of php5-fpm and nginx but there are no errors. 
How to make it execute?

Comment: echo "<img src="/foto.jpg" />" for 2nd line

Comment: $output is just a result of command execution it does not have file attached. Just include your file as an image.

Comment: Does it create `/var/www/html/foto.jpg` file when you run it?

Comment: @E_p It doesn't create foto.jpg.

Comment: @Matrix did you try to run `/usr/bin/fswebcam -S 1 -r 640x480 -q /var/www/html/foto.jpg` in a command line by itself as a www-data user?

Comment: @E_p `sudo -u www-data /usr/bin/fswebcam -S 1 -r 640x480 -q /var/www/html/foto.jpg` works fine if file already exists, then foto.jpg is updated.
But if I run that command from php file it still does nothing.

Comment: `shell_exec('/var/www/html/foto.jpg')` as first command?

Comment: What should it do? Because it does nothing. I also added `echo "Test";` at the end of the file, and when I add your `shell_exec` as first command I get a blank page.

Comment: `shell_exec('touch /var/www/html/foto.jpg')` - stupid me. Just to make sure that file exists before you  run your command.

Comment: @E_p "Test" showed up again, but photo.jpg isn't updated. This command with fswebcam needs some time (like 1 second) to execute. Maybe that is the problem? But even after refreshing the page few times it doesn't work.

Comment: As an idea split in to 2 parts one is a cron/deamon screapt that runs every 10 seconds and page just has 1 image tag with refresh button.  An yes long execution time might be the problem

Comment: @E_p that can be a workaround. I attached syslog to fswebcam and got something wrong probably with permissions: `Error opening device: /dev/video0`

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=60464&p=451336) the solution is to uncomment `cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1` in php.ini file. This worked well for me.